# Will the recent US tariffs against Scottish (and more generally UK) products cease to apply after Brexit?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, brexit, trade, tariffs

The BBC has [some details](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-50095338) as to the list of products tariffed by the US as a result of the Airbus WTO ruling. Among these

> Single malt Scotch whisky
>
> According to the Scotch Whisky Association (SWA), Scotland exported about $1.3bn of Scotch to the US in 2018 - 33% of which was single malt.
>
> That translates to just under 25 million bottles of single malt Scotch.
>
> SWA chief executive Karen Betts has warned that "jobs could be at risk" at Scottish distilleries as a result of the tariffs.

Toward the end of the article cashmere products are mentioned too, apparently affecting other areas of the UK exporting them.

Do the US tariffs cease to apply to the UK (including Scotland) after Brexit?

Comment: Airbus builds a lot of the substructures of it’s aircraft in the UK, so the tariffs would still be valid.

Comment: An interesting follow up would be the status of the UK in the Beoing case next year. If the WTO case allows the EU to place tariffs against the US for state support, but the UK is out of the EU...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is highly likely the tariffs will remain in place.

The [press release](https://ustr.gov/about-us/policy-offices/press-office/press-releases/2019/october/us-wins-75-billion-award-airbus) specifically calls out four countries that the US says is behind most of the illegal state subsidies that triggered the tariffs: France, Germany, Spain, and the UK.  While it does not specifically mention the issue of Brexit, the fact that the UK is specifically called out in this way would suggest that Brexit will make no difference with regard to these tariffs being applied to British exports.

Comment: I guess you mean (in your 1st sentence) it's highly likely the tariffs will continue after Brexit.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: That's the tariffs against the UK. The EU will likely take counter measures.